# How to get arglist from a function handle?

Tags: matlab, function, arguments, handle

I have the following function handle

```
 fun = @(x,y,z)[x.^3+y.^2+z.^2,x.^2-y.^3+sin(z)]
```

And now I am using the function

```
jacobian(fun, [x,y,z])
```

which returns the jacobian of the function. To use this function I first need to define

```
syms x y z.
```

If the function changes to

```
@(x,y,z,w)[x.^3+y.^2+z.^2+w,x.^2-y.^3+sin(z)+w]
```

the jacobian is returned by

```
jacobian(fun, [x,y,z,w]).
```

Now I don't want to change the second input argument of the jacobian manually. Is there a function in Matlab, that looks at the function handles and returns them, or returns how many there are?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
str = func2str(fun); %// get fun's defining string
str = regexp(str, '^@\([^\)]+\)', 'match'); %// keep only "@(...)" part
vars = regexp(str{1}(3:end-1), ',', 'split'); %// remove "@(" and ")", and  split by commas
jacobian(fun, sym(vars)); %// convert vars to sym and use it as input to jacobian
```

Example:

```
>> clear all
>> syms r s t
>> fun = @(r,s,t) [r*s^t r+s*t]
fun = 
    @(r,s,t)[r*s^t,r+s*t]
>> str = func2str(fun);
   str = regexp(str, '^@\([^\)]+\)', 'match');
   vars = regexp(str{1}(3:end-1), ',', 'split');
   jacobian(fun, sym(vars))
ans =
[ s^t, r*s^(t - 1)*t, r*s^t*log(s)]
[   1,             t,            s]
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting (_completing_) my answer. I am very inexperienced with the symbolic toolbox so I didn't want to venture a wild guess. Nice answer too. I love when I learn something new.

Comment: I don't use the symbolic toolbox very often either. That's one good thing about Stack Overflow: it spurs you to try things and learn! :-)

Answer (score 1):

the [`functions`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html) function and a quick regex can help you:

```
fun = @(x,y,z,w)[x.^3+y.^2+z.^2+w,x.^2-y.^3+sin(z)+w] ;

s = functions(fun) ;
strVar = strsplit( char( regexp(s.function, '\(([^\)]+)\)' , 'tokens' , 'once' )) ,',') ;
nInput = numel(strVar) ;
```

will get you:

```
>> strVar
strVar = 
    'x'    'y'    'z'    'w'
>> nInput
nInput =
     4
```

---

edit: Many thanks to Luis Mendo's comment.

You will need to add something like:

```
sym(strVar(:))
```

to declare them as symbolic variables, or directly:

```
jacobian(fun, sym(strVar))
```

to calculate your jacobian.

Comment: I think you need a final step to convert `strVar` to `sym`, as `jacobian` expects `sym` input. See my answer. +1 for the approach though